# DataSet.HasChanges is true even immediately after TableAdapter.Update is run

Tags: .net, data-binding, dataset, tableadapter

I've got some legacy dataset code which I'm updating. I'm attempting to determine if the dataset has changes to it so I can properly prompt for a save request. However myDataset.HasChanges() always returns true.

In my save method I've edited the code to determine when the dataset get's changes and made the code like this:

```
1. myBindingSource.EndEdit()
2. myTableAdapter.Update(myDataSet)
3. myBindingSource.EndEdit()
```

After line 1, - myDataSet.HasChanges = true (understandable)
After line 2, - myDataSet.HasChanges = false (understandable)
After line 3, - myDataSet.HasChanges = true

I'm unsure of why this would occur in line 3, shouldn't this be false because I just ran the updates on the dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be an UI element causing a value to change within the dataSet/dataTable.

Try your code in a simple consoleApplication without any DataBinding.

Comment: There are databound items that fired off events that "changed, but didn't change" data

Comment: @NathanKoop Did you figure out a fix? I'm having this exact same problem.

Comment: If I recall correctly (it was a few years ago), I believe that I had an Textbox.OnChange event firing and that would modify some other textboxes, which would then change the dataset.

Comment: @styfle to expand a bit more, I think what I ended up doing was add an IsSaving bool, and in my events I checked IsSaving, and ignored the UI modification. There is probably a better way, but I was in a rush and then the project moved on.

Answer (score 1):

Does your TableAdapter refresh your DataSet?  If it does, then you probably have something like a key getting initialized (remember, GUID==good, Int==bad).  It's just like when you fill from a TableAdapter you need to call AcceptChanges to reset the state of all of the rows to unchanged.

Comment: I'm not sure if the TableAdapter refresh's the data. All it does is an UPDATE ... WHERE id = @myId; I tried adding an AcceptChanges in there (between lines 2 & 3) and I still got the same result. I am using int's (not my db design and I can't change it). There also shouldn't be any key's getting initialized, in the situation I'm testing, I load the form (tons of databindings etc...) and then press the save button without changing any of the data and this occurs